# node.js and express - debugging a route

Tags: node.js, debugging, express

I am trying to debug my routes while using NodeJS and the Express framework. I installed node-inspector and got it fully working and open in a Chrome tab. Nevertheless, it isn't showing anything when I have this code in my index.js route

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    var $ = require('jquery');
    console.log($('.title').val);
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

I'm wondering what the reason behind this is. I hope someone can help!

Edit: When I place a `console.log` in the app.js the debugger isn't showing anything either. 
Other info:

- I am using Windows
- I first run `node-inspector`
- And then in a second terminal I run `node --debug-brk app.js`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem:

**But this ->** `console.log($('.title').val);`

**should be this ->** `console.log($('.title').val());`

But honestly I don't think jQuery works well with Node on the backend side. I have used it with express on the client side, but not on the server side.

**I have seen this jQuery install for Node:**

`npm install jquery` 
https://npmjs.org/package/jquery

I haven't used this install with node so I cannot be certain this works.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that wasn't the solution and jquery is installed and as you've seen required in the code. The problem is that I can't see anything that I'm logging.

Comment: Did you get the install from here? https://npmjs.org/package/jquery And if so did you have any problems with Windows like they mentioned?

Comment: I did get the problems, but I solved it by installing some Microsoft components like .NET framework and visual studio. But agian, the problem lies in the debugger.